# How to get list of all products available for inapp nilling

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing

I am trying to implement inapp purchase in my application. I am following [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/how-to-integrate-in-app-purchase-billing-in-android.html) tutorial. Now I need to get the price of all items available for save from the inapp product list on server. How can I do that?

I have seen this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html). But this uses inapp biling V3.  But I am following a different one I guess. How can I do the same in my current implementation?

Comment: You should seriously consider switching to In-App Billing V3. It is greatly improved in both reliability and ease of use over previous versions - the tutorials available on the official site go through the full process in detail.

Comment: It's probably not possible for versions prior to V3 to accomplish this, basically your app would have to know all the in-app products beforehand. As @ianhanniballake said, you should consider switching to V3 unless there's some specific reason that prevents you from doing so.